# Strongly connected Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

I have a strongly connected graph. I want to remove an edge and check if still remains strongly connected. As i'm taking N = Total number of nodes in the graph to be 10 and most of the graphs that i'm interested in has above 25 edges its hard to check using one at a time removing edge.

How to solve this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If the edge you remove is (*u* -> *v*), the graph will remain connected if you can find a path from *u* to *v*. You can use any path finding algorithm to check this.

Another option is to run a connectivity check algorithm from scratch every time; it doesn't really matter how you do this because the graph is very small.

For a larger graph, there are special data structures that have been designed for this problem. It's called "Dynamic connectivity": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity

Comment: Was thinking in same direction as u have mentioned in first line.

Comment: You don't need to check whether there's a path v->...->u: There must have been some such path previously, and no such path could have used the edge u->v, which is the only change we made.

Comment: Yes, that was a silly thinko. I edited it out just before your comment. :)

Comment: Hence finding total number of paths between two nodes and then if its 1 i can stop.

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT: DFS is faster than Dijkstra for just checking connectivity, thanks to Jørgen Fogh]**

If the edge you're removing is uv, check (e.g. using DFS) whether there remains a path u->...->v.  If so, the graph is still strongly connected if it was before.  If not, then it's clearly no longer strongly connected.

The idea is that any path between two vertices x and y that previously used the edge uv can be edited to use the new path u->...->v.  Simply replacing the edge uv with this new path might cause some vertices to be visited more than once -- but in this case, the path contains one or more directed cycles which can be removed, until the remaining path visits each vertex at most once.

Comment: Dijkstra's Algorithm may not be applicable here, since the OP does not specify that the edges have weights. A normal depth-first search will work and is much easier to implement.